# C# Excel - Only read / select Cells with values/data

Tags: c#, excel

How can I read an excel file and select ONLY those CELLS that have data - not formatting, not spaces , just text or numbers.

I know I can read the spreadsheet like this: How can I do a 'select' on only those cells and make a copy.  Thanks in advance

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    if (excelApp != null)
    {
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

        Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
        int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                Excel.Range range = (excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range);
                string cellValue = range.Value.ToString();

                //do anything
            }
        }

        excelWorkbook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.specialcells?view=excel-pia

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing methodology what you are missing is comparing the value to string.empty and knowing that you can use Excel.Application.Union to combine ranges.

Consider this psuedocode (aka I did not run it.)

**Let it be noted,** that if you want precision (more than what excel formats to show the user) you should use .Value2 instead of .Value.

```
public void CopyValues()
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

                Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
                int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
                int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;

                Excel.Range copyRange = null;

                for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                    {
                        Excel.Range range = (excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range);
                        if (range.Value.ToString().Trim() != string.Empty)
                        {
                            if (copyRange == null)
                            {
                                copyRange = range;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //Its got somehting so union it in
                                copyRange = excelApp.Union(copyRange, range);
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
                //Copy to clipboard
                copyRange.Copy();

                excelWorkbook.Close();
                excelApp.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi.. thx, But Get System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'This action won't work on multiple selections.'
Copy()    also why does rowcount return 1 when I have 1000+,  colcount is correct

Comment: Well looking at it, it is actually not possible to copy non-contiguous sections in excel so you would have to slightly modify your request.  You might be able to select them, but you would not be able to just copy them all directly to the clipboard as is.

Comment: Basically the reason this logic holds true is usually you have explanations pre or postfixed to values such as Total Subtotal etc.  If you don't zoom in on what you want to pull out you cant ensure the area comes out where each would be equivalent allowing you to (without blanks) retag what something actually is.